# Trouble launching game and music (at the same time) when pressing 'run' on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, background-music

I have this code to play music (found online):

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.applet.AudioClip;
import java.net.URL;

public class MusicBackground {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


        URL url = MusicBackground.class.getResource("backgroundMusic.wav");
        AudioClip clip = Applet.newAudioClip(url);
        clip.play();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        clip.loop();
    }
}
```

It works fine alone. But the thing is that after I implemented it into my game, it either plays the music when I'm launching the music class, or when I run the entire game, it runs the game without the music. Here is my Boot class for my game:

```
import static helpers.Artist.BeginSession;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import helpers.Clock;
import helpers.StateManager;

public class Boot {
    public Boot() {

        //Call static method in Artist class to initialize OpenGL calls
        BeginSession();

        //Main game loop
        while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
            Clock.update();
            StateManager.update();
            Display.update();
            Display.sync(60);
        }
        Display.destroy();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Boot();
    }
}
```

I know that the music background class is in public static void main. But how do I implement it into the boot class ?

Comment: You probably need to copy/paste the 5 lines from your music code into your boot class. You might also need to run that code in a separate thread.
You can create a method in your boot class let's say private static void playMusic() {} and call it in your main method after/before your new Boot() call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your background music class to implement runnable:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.applet.AudioClip;
import java.net.URL;
import java.lang.Runnable;

public class MusicBackground implements Runnable {

public void run() throws Exception {
URL url = MusicBackground.class.getResource("backgroundMusic.wav");
AudioClip clip = Applet.newAudioClip(url);
clip.play();
Thread.sleep(1000);
clip.loop();
}
}
```

Then you can spawn a thread for the background music in your game's main thread. If you just direct call or paste that background music code in the main game loop, then the .sleep call will cause the entire program to sleep (as it is currently one thread). So, this is what your main method will look like now:

```
import static helpers.Artist.BeginSession;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import helpers.Clock;
import helpers.StateManager;

public class Boot {

public Boot() {

    //Call static method in Artist class to initialize OpenGL calls
    BeginSession();
    Thread backgroundPlayer;
    Try {
        backgroundPlayer = new Thread(new MusicBackground());
        backgroundPlayer.start();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Problem firing the background thread");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //Main game loop
    while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
        Clock.update();
        StateManager.update();
        Display.update();
        Display.sync(60);
    }
    Display.destroy();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
new Boot();
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! Love you !