# Is there anyway to have a for loop running in the background and another task at the front?

Tags: java, for-loop, keylistener

I have a background image that scrolls down constantly, but I'm placing a menu over it and need a keylistner and music overtop of it. However I can't seem to get the keylistener to start. My assumption is it's due to the for loop which resets itself right before it reaches its end.

```
//Backloop is called before keyPressed in the main class
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent VK_DOWN) {
    down();
}
public void backloop() throws InterruptedException {
    for(int x = 1; x > -4320; x--) {
        if(x == -4000)
        {
            x = 0;
            rolling.setLocation(0, x);
        }else {
            rolling.setLocation(0, x);
            Thread.sleep(50);
        }

    }
}

public void down() {
    if(title = false)
    {
        panel.remove(title1);
        panel.add(title2);
        title = true;
    }else {
        panel.remove(title2);
        panel.add(title1);
        title = false;
    }
}
```

I expect the output to have the background image in the for-loop running and the title screen to change when the down arrow is pressed, however it only runs the background loop

Comment: That's called multi-threading. Google?

Comment: Threads allow multiple concurrent flows of execution. See the high level interfaces provided in `java.util.concurrent`, starting with the `Executors` class.

Comment: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=153

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program has one thread right now. As such, it cannot do two things at one time. However, the good news is that you can multi-thread your program so that it will do multiple things at one time.

I answered a similar question to this one here: [Trouble launching game and music (at the same time) when pressing 'run' on Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55424082/trouble-launching-game-and-music-at-the-same-time-when-pressing-run-on-eclip/55424327#55424327).

You can put your background loop in a class and implement `Runnable`. This will allow you to run that for loop in the background. The above link shows how to modify code in order to move your program from single threaded to multi-threaded.